# Relational Model Objects struggle

Tags: php, object, models, relational, mapper

I finally want to get into data models. But there is one thing I can't wrap my head around, and I hope this won't sound too stupid:

How or when to set the ID of the object ?
What I mean is, when creating an object, there is no way to know what ID this object is going to have when inserted into the database ( by a mapper class ). So how can I persist relational objects if I dont know the IDs yet ?

I will try to explain this by an example:

```
class product {

  private $id; // ??
  private $name;
  private $color;

  function __construct( $name, color $color ){
    $this->name = $name;  
    $this->color = $color;
  }

  function getName(){
    return $this->name;
  }

  function getColor(){
    return $this->color;
  }  

  function setId(){
    $this->id = $id;
  }


}

class color {

  private $id; // ??
  private $hexCode;

  function __construct( $hexCode ){
    $this->hexCode = $hexCode;
  }

  function getId(){
    return $this->id;
  }

}


class productMapper{

  function persist( product $product ){

    // persist query 
    $someQueryBuilder->insert('products')->set('name',$product->getName())->set('refColor',$product->getColor()->getId()); 

    $product->setId( $someQueryBuilder->getInsertId() );

  }

}


$color = new color('FFCC00');
$product = new product( 'table', $color );


$productMapper = new productMapper();
$productMapper->persist( $product );
```

So my problem here is, I cannot persist my `product` object, as my `color` object has no ID yet.
What is the right way to do this ??
Or is my approach here simply wrong ?

Thank you for helping me out or maybe just pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Add an auto_increment Primary Key to your products table on the id column.

Answer (score 0):

As you planned here, you need no Id for the product or color.

However if you insist in having an Id for these classes (for example if you have these objects also in database tables), you must plan some codes in these classes to set the Id for the objects.

```
class product {

  private $id;
  private $name;
  private $color;
  private static $last_id;

  function __construct( $name, color $color ){
    $this->last_id++;
    $this->id=$this->last_id;
    $this->name = $name;  
    $this->color = $color;
  }

  function getName(){
    return $this->name;
  }

  function getColor(){
    return $this->color;
  }  

  function getId(){
    return $this->id;
  }
}

class color {

  private $id;
  private $hexCode;
  private static $last_id;

  function __construct( $hexCode ){
    $this->last_id++;
    $this->id=$this->last_id;
    $this->hexCode = $hexCode;
  }

  function getId(){
    return $this->id;
  }

}


class productMapper{

  function persist( product $product ){

    // persist query 
    $someQueryBuilder->insert('products')->set('name',$product->getName())->set('refColor',$product->getColor()->getId()); 

    $product->setId( $someQueryBuilder->getInsertId() );

  }

}


$color = new color('FFCC00');
$product = new product( 'table', $color );


$productMapper = new productMapper();
$productMapper->persist( $product );
```